Load data when text is pasted in a form
I have a search form that reacts when someone is typing in it. I want it to react when something is pasted into as well, is it possible? As it is now, the pasted text must be followed by a space.
<input type="text" name="search_text" id="search_text" placeholder="&#xf002;" class="fontAwesome" />

<div id="result"></div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        load_data();
        function load_data(query) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "oSearch.php",
                method: "POST",
                data: { query: query },
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#result").html(data);
                },
            });
        }
        $("#search_text").keyup(function () {
            var search = $(this).val();
            if (search != "") {
                load_data(search);
            } else {
                load_data();
            }
        });
    });
</script>


there is a well supported "paste" event

You can make use of the "paste" event, see below how to listen to multiple events using jquery


function debounce(callback, delay) {
var timeoutHandler = null;
return function () {
    clearTimeout(timeoutHandler);
    timeoutHandler = setTimeout(function () {
        callback();
    }, delay);
}
}
$('#search_text').on('keyup paste', debounce(function(e){
  console.log($('#search_text').val());
}, 500));
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="search_text" id="search_text" placeholder="&#xf002;" class="fontAwesome">



PS: I would recommend to use some kind of "throttling" to not make an ajaxcall every keyup (paste will trigger keyup as well), see -> How to delay the .keyup() handler until the user stops typing?

Thanks for your inputs. I tried the keyup paste but it still don't work in Safari (iPhone).

i just tested with an iphone and safari and you are right, but for me it triggers but this.value is empty, when pasting again it logs only the last-value, there seems to be some bug..

I could get around the bug by adding a throttle/debounce function, let me know if this works for you too!

In the console log everything works good also in Safari. I can't get it work together with my code, where shall I put the debounce function?

in the code you posted in the question you could just add the function definition right after the opening <script> tag

Tried without sucess, the function stop working. I also added , 500 in my code as
$('#search_text').on('keyup paste', debounce(function(e){
var search = $(this).val();
if(search != '')
{
load_data(search);
}
else
{
load_data();
}
}, 500));
});
 Have I done something wrong?
